# How to set log level to trace for Confd logs such as netconfTraceLog, netconfLog, etc?

Tags: ssh, netconf, confd

**Setup:**

I have developed a Netconf client. It connects to a Confd server over SSH. My Netconf client is able to establish an SSH connection and SSH channel. I see related Confd logs as listed below.

```
<INFO> 19-May-2023::20:41:38.554 vm-alarm confd[298881]: audit user: admin/0 local authentication succeeded via netconf from 10.0.2.15:37954 with ssh, member of groups: admin
<INFO> 19-May-2023::20:41:38.555 vm-alarm confd[298881]: audit user: admin/0 logged in via Netconf from 10.0.2.15:37954 with ssh using local authentication
```

When my client sends Hello message, it does not receive any response. After a generous timeout period of 2 minutes, it closes the SSH connection. I do not see any confd logs generated for this step.

**Logs enabled on Confd:**

I have enabled the confd logs such as netconfTraceLog, netconfLog & auditLog.

I have set developerLogLevel to trace level by adding the following line, as documented in ConfD User guide.

```
<developerLogLevel>trace</developerLogLevel>
```

**Query**

Is it possible to set log level to trace for the logs such as netconfTraceLog, netconfLog & auditLog?